# How to Use Gradle to bypass login screen

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I would like to bypass the login screen in my app while development. Can I use gradle product flavor to accomplish this ? Currenlty I use the following approach

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            mPresenter.onLoginClick("xxx", "yyy");
        }
```

Is it possible to have this code in just one of the product flavor instead of all the debug builds ?

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants) you can add flavors using the `productFlavors` closure under the `android` element in your build script.

For your flavors you can use `buildConfigField` to add an option, for example `buildConfigField "boolean", "SKIP_LOGIN", "true"`. Then in your app you can check this build-time value by looking at `BuildConfig.SKIP_LOGIN`.

Comment: I dont want to have this check under main folder , instead want to have it just in one of product flavors

Comment: Ah my bad, I misread your question. Well, my suggestion will get you what you required although with a slightly different implementation. What you want exactly could be achieved through http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger, however someone else might be able to shed more light on that, or provide some sort of functional sample.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into this